# Forcing VS Code to install an extension without compatibility checking

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-chrome-os

I am using [a custom build version](https://code.headmelted.com/) of the Visual Studio Code. It seems some extensions are checking the exact build name and version of the vscode before installation and if it doesn't match, vscode throws an error:

> Unable to install because, the extension '....' compatible with
> current version '...' of VS Code is not found.

For example, the [Remote - SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) extension on my current custom build throws:

> Unable to install because, the extension 'ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh'
> compatible with current version '1.32.0' of VS Code is not found.

---

Is there a way to bypass the version checking and force vs-code to allow the installation?

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

There are two issues to concern:

1. The first one is a legal one. The Remote - SSH extension's license is very restrictive. From [its license](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/license):

   > You may use a copy of the software with each validly licensed copy of Microsoft Visual Studio Code. You may not use the software if you do not have a license for Microsoft Visual Studio Code.
2. The second one is the extension's incompatibility. It seems that your custom build is based on VS Code version `1.32.0`. However, the initial release of the SSH extension requires at least VS Code `1.35.0` or above. From the [release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_35#_remote-development-preview) of VS Code `1.35.0`:

   > The Remote Development extensions are now available for VS Code Stable [...]

## Conclusion

So even if you do not care about the legal issues and are able to force install the extension for your custom build it will probably not work since the extension requires a more recent release of VS Code.

More information on this topic can be found in the [VSCodium documentation](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/blob/master/DOCS.md#extensions--marketplace) (A "[free version](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium#why-does-this-exist)" of VSCode). If you rely on the SSH extension and consider switching your custom build, there you will find a possible workaround to get the remote extensions working with VSCodium (I haven't tested it on my own).